# Right-align a currency string (with no symbol)?

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I currently output a currency value left-aligned, using the following:

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:#,##0}", value);
```

I wish to modify the string formatter so that I can right align this. Im not sure how to do it without affecting my existing formatter.

Could someone please advise?

EDIT: I Know it involves something similar to:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/

Comment: How do you `right align` a string??

Comment: What kind of application are you working on? Web? Desktop? Where are the data displayed? Maybe you can set the data container align property (div, textbox)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Format("{0,20:#,##0}", value);` will do it.

[Example.](http://ideone.com/x2xGv)

Answer (score 0):

not very clear what you actually mean, but I *suppose*, you are talking about

[String.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx.aspx) method.

Example: to "align" right, you can:

```
string hello  ="hello"; 
int supportedSymbCount = 10;
int padcount = supportedSymbCount - hello.Length;
if(padCount>0)
   hello = hello.PadLeft(padCount);
```

This will add "pads" in *front* of the string as much as need to compose a string as long as `10` characters. Choose parameters more sutable to you, and it should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

For console output use the tab character as a separator,

```
Console.WriteLine( "\t{0:#,##0}", value )
```

For web use div class="numeric" with text-align="right".

For other outputs there are no generic solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PadLeft` or `PadRight`

```
int iTotalLength = 20; // Total length of string
char cPadChar = '0'; // Padding character
String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:#,##0}", value).PadLeft(iTotalLength, 
                                                                      cPadChar);
```